# How to Determine and Set Screen Size at run time using action script?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, screen-size

Hey so i am developing an android application using action script(the adobe air one) since the screen size of my .swf application is appox 840X480... Can i detect the screen size of the android device running application at runtime and set the screen size accordingly?? if so How?? 
P.S - I'm still rookie at Action-script
Thank You

Comment: There a few ways.  Read this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/multiple-screen-sizes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to make your app liquid (or responsive).  Follow the following steps:

1. Set the stage align and scale modes:

   ```
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
   stage.align     = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
   ```
2. Listen for resize events on the stage:

   ```
   stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, stageResizeHandler);

   function stageResizeHandler(e:Event):void {
       stage.stageWidth; //how big the width is
       stage.stageHeight; //how big the height is.

       //so if you had a box, and you wanted it centered on the screen:
       box.x = (stage.stageWidth - box.width) * .5;
       box.y = (stage.stageHeight - box.height) * .5;

       //draw a background
       graphics.clear();
       graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
       graphics.drawRect(0,0,stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
       graphics.endFill();
   }
   ```

If, you just want to know the physical size of the display, you can do so in the `Capabilities` class:

```
Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

OR

```
stage.fullScreenWidth;
stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

This usually doesn't include any tool bars /notification bars though.

If you just want your content scaled, then set the scale mode to whatever you'd like:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_BORDER; 
//this will zoom in your app until it fills the whole screen, though it may crop it a bit if needed.
```

To see other scaling modes, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776458/how-to-make-flash-animation-responsive/27786709#27786709)