# Bitmaps not scaling correctly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapimage

I was experimenting with bitmaps and created an alpha mask.  When i test the program in full screen, it works fine however when I re-size the screen, the bitmap alpha masks doesn't seem to scale correctly. Below are illustrations of my issue. The bitmap alpha mask is shown as a purple background for visibility, and the blue portion is where the bitmap is completely transparent.

Full Screen (Looks Good)
[image: Full Screen]

Regular Screen (Looks like the mask is shifted to the left):
[image: Regular Screen]

Why is this happening and what can i do to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "shifted to the left"? What are your settings for resizing?

Comment: Currently i dont have any callbacks for the resizing,  I thought everything resized itself automatically unless you told it otherwise.

Look at the last "c" on both of the images. the first picture has the last "c" completely surrounded by blue, and the second picture has the last "c" almost completely surrounded by blue.

Comment: Have you setup any stageAlign / scaleMode setings?   Maybe look at my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27786709/1457439

Comment: I think the secoɳd one is Better :D .I think same as @Batman. you have to work with `stage.align` or `stage.scaleMode`,etc.

Comment: Hey guys, great suggestions. I really appreciate your help, i tried playing with the stage scaleMode and  stage align however; i could not get it to fix my problem.

However I figured out the problem was because my text box width was greater than the stage width. I changed the width of the text box to match the stage width and everything works fine now.

Comment: Ignore the last half of the previous comment. I found out it wasn't working because of the anti-aliasing. The text box width modification was just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the text box Anti-aliasing was the problem. I changed the ani-aliasing from "Anti-alias for readability" to "Anti-alias for animation"  and now everything scales properly.