# AS3 Issues with Rotation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rotation, air

I have a fairly basic app where you navigate menus and then access videos and demos.

My issue is that when you access a video, it forces you to rotate the screen first.

By using stage.scaleMode = Stage.ScaleMode.NO_SCALE I was able to make it work perfectly on my iPhone 7, but I can't find a way to scale up for iPhone 8 or 10.

I've been trying to use other StageScaleModes, and they work perfectly for the menus but when the screen is rotated, the scale becomes insanely wonky.

It either stays within the original aspect ratio or becomes much to big for the screen.

I've tried using stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight to correct this but they never return the correct size.

Any help in either fixing the issue in rotation or making NO_SCALE work would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

```
public function playVideo(path2: String): Function {
        path = path2;
        var listener: * ;
        listener = function (e: MouseEvent = null): void {
            stage.addChild(pleaseRotateScreen);
            stage.autoOrients = true; 
            stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChangeListener_Videos);
        }
        return listener;
    }


    function orientationChangeListener_Videos(e: StageOrientationEvent) {
        if (e.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT || e.afterOrientation == StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT) {
            stage.removeEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChangeListener_Videos);
            stage.autoOrients = false;
            stage.removeChild(pleaseRotateScreen);
            startVideo();
        }
    }
```

EDIT2

public function startVideo(): void { //bring up the video UI.
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

```
        headerTextField = new TextField();
        headerTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        var theFont = new BrownReg();
        var rectClip: Sprite = new Sprite();
        headerTextField.autoSize = "left";
        //headerTextField.text = pageClip2.uiText;
        headerTextField.text = "Stage Width: " + stage.width + " Stage.Height: " + stage.stageHeight;
        headerTextField.selectable = false;


        backPlate = new MovieClip;
        backPlate.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        backPlate.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        backPlate.graphics.endFill();
        overlay = new blackOverlay;
        video_UI.addChild(overlay);
        overlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bringUpVideoUI);

        mcScroll.addChild(backPlate);

        TweenLite.to(menu_clip, .4, { alpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });
        TweenLite.to(screen_clip, .4, { alpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });
        TweenLite.to(pageClip, .4, { alpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });
        TweenLite.to(mcScroll, .4, { alpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });
        TweenLite.to(topbar_clip, .4, { alpha: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut });

        video_UI.addChild(gradientVid);
        gradientVid.y = 750 - 100;

        X_UI = new videoX;       
        X_UI.x = (1254+24); X_UI.y = (678+24);
        video_UI.addChild(X_UI);
        X_UI.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeVideo);

        pauseUI = new MovieClip;  
        pauseUI.addChild(pauseClip); 
        pauseUI.x = (140+24);   pauseUI.y = (672+30);
        video_UI.addChild(pauseUI);
        pauseUI.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVid);

        jumpBackUI = new mcFastForward;   
        jumpBackUI.rotation = 180;
        jumpBackUI.x = (32+30); jumpBackUI.y = (672+30);
        video_UI.addChild(jumpBackUI);
        jumpBackUI.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekBack);

        jumpForwardUI = new mcFastForward;   
        jumpForwardUI.x = (248+30);     jumpForwardUI.y = (672+30);
        video_UI.addChild(jumpForwardUI);
        jumpForwardUI.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, seekForward);


        var f: TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        headerTextField.x = 32;     headerTextField.y = 60;

        f.size = 48; 
        f.font = theFont.fontName;
        f.color = 0xffffff;

        headerTextField.embedFonts = true;
        headerTextField.setTextFormat(f);
        video_UI.addChild(headerTextField);

        video_UI.alpha = 0;

        videoRect.width = stage.stageWidth;  
        videoRect.height = stage.stageHeight;
        //videoRect.scaleX = videoRect.scaleY;
        initVideo();

        bringUpVideoUI();
    }
```

[Before Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSp0h.png)

[After Rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3Jmw.png)

Edit 3:

```
public function initVideo(): void {
        var obj: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var nc: NetConnection = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        netstream = new NetStream(nc);
        netstream.client = obj;
        obj.onMetaData = onMetaData;

        stageVideo = stage.stageVideos[0];
        stageVideo.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, onRender);
        stageVideo.attachNetStream(netstream);

        netstream.play(path);
        netstream.seek(0);

        netstream.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        netstream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        netstream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, doAsyncError);
        netstream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, doNetStatus);
        netstream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, doIOError);

        if (netstream != null) { 
            netstream.removeEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, doAsyncError);
            netstream.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, doNetStatus);
            netstream.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, doIOError);
        }
    }


    //Video Functions
    public function shrinkVideo() { }
    public function enlargeVideo() { }
    protected function doSecurityError(evt: SecurityErrorEvent): void {     trace("AbstractStream.securityError:" + evt.text);      }
    protected function doIOError(evt: IOErrorEvent): void {     trace("AbstractScreem.ioError:" + evt.text);        }
    protected function doAsyncError(evt: AsyncErrorEvent) {     trace("AsyncError:" + evt.text);        }
    protected function doNetStatus(evt: NetStatusEvent): void {     }
    private function onMetaData(e: Object): void {      duration = e.duration;      }
    private function onRender(e: StageVideoEvent): void {   
        if(videoDemo == true){ 
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
            cl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _handleClick); //add the clickforward to the the rectangle. 
        }
        stageVideo.viewPort = videoRect;        
    }

    private function netStatusHandler(e: NetStatusEvent): void { //get the end of a video
        if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
            if (demo == true) {
                netstream.play(path); //loop the video if its in a demo
            } else if (videoDemo == true) { 
                returnFromDemo(); 
            }else{
                exitVid();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please share your relevant code.  A screenshot would likely be helpful as well.   Most likely, you need to listen for the stage resize event (which will be triggered on the orientation change) and then size your video accordingly.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what is relevant. Its a fairly long script, and I don't currently have anything that seems to be Doing this or not.

That said, stage resize seems like it will be helpful but it only seems to be triggering on NO_SCALE mode? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the stage is only resized if it's set to NO_SCALE,  otherwise instead of being resized, it's just scaled.  For explanation of scaling options see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27786709/1457439

Comment: What's relevant, would be the code where you play the video (that causes the screen to rotate).   Presumably this is an AIR project if your using iPhones, so listening for resize on the `stage.nativeWindow` will work regardless of the stage scale mode

Comment: Added the code to the original post. 
I'm not forcing it to rotate, instead I'm turning autoorients on and then waiting for the user to rotate.

I'll give your suggestions a shot too! THank you for your help!

Comment: Can you show the code for `StartVideo`?  I'd like to see how you're sizing your video.

Comment: Added! When I was using NO_SCALE I was just sizing by the stage size, so width = 1334 and height = 750

Comment: I still don't see your actual video code, which I suppose is in `initVideo`?

Comment: Put it in there as well. The video isn't the only thing not scaling correctly though, the UI is in the same boat.
I am trying to use the resize event, but on anything thats not NO_SCALE it doesn't actually change the stageWidth.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look when I have a moment.   For the UI,  if you have the stage set to no scale, you need resize the UI manually to fit properly.  Look at the second half of this answer I made many moons ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34163821/1457439 for some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: At first glance it all looks ok.  Make sure you have top_left as your stage align, and you could also try entering full screen mode and using stage.fullScreenHeight / width  as your viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

When developing a multiscreen game or app, developers need to read device's screen size to correctly rescale and reorganise screen elements.
These sizing issues can be very frustrating, especially as behavior is not the same across OSes and devices.
My personal preference is to always have my apps run in 
fullscreenMode = true / aspectRatio = portrait / autoOrients = false, only.
If there is a need to redraw/resize stuff based on a change in orientation, then a handler should be able to 'fake' it, rather than actually modifying the stage.